# Losing jQuery autocomplete "Select" functionality when implementing custom HTML menu

Tags: jquery, html, menu, autocomplete

I am trying to implement jQuery autocomplete with a custom drop down menu. I am able to customize menu items with the data()._renderItem method (commented out) ,but this disables the menu "Select" functionality. If I attempt to customize menu items via the "label" field The "Select" functionality works but my menu item HTML is interpreted as a string. Can anyone suggest a clean way of accomplishing this.

```
$("input#selectedInput")

.bind("autocompleteselect", function (event, ui) {
alert("Sel item " + JSON.stringify(ui.item.json));
})



.autocomplete({
appendTo: "#list",
source: function (request, response) {
    //alert("success");
    $.ajax({
        //url: "http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&entity=musicTrack",
        url: "Example REST URL",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            featureClass: "P",
            style: "full",
            maxRows: 12,
            name_startsWith: request.term
        },

        success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data.results, function (item) {
                itunesJson = item;
                return {
                    label: "<li><img src='" + item.artworkUrl30 + "' alt='no photo'/>" + item.trackName + "</li>",
                }
            }));
        },
    });
}
})
/*
        .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append("<img src='"+item.value+"' alt='no photo'/>"+ item.label)
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
        */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try placing anchor tags around your image in the return html eg.
...

```
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
return $( "<li></li>" )
         .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
         .append("<a><img src='"+item.value+"' alt='no photo'/></a>"+ item.label)
         .appendTo( ul );
```

Comment: Actually you have to have anchor tags as your root node in your LI for custom autocomplete to function at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read here: http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/.
This is what I use when I need autocomplete. It's really easy to configure.
And please tell me, if it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: OP is trying to make a dropdownlist using jquery ui autocomplete here

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your response. I was however looking for a solution that was restricted jQuery Mobile's autocomplete library (i.e. no further plugins).

Comment: Ok. So how about this one: http://www.andymatthews.net/read/2012/03/27/jQuery-Mobile-Autocomplete-now-available

Answer (score 0):

One simple workaround will be to [HTML Encode `list` using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219983/17447) after label has been assigned on success call

```
var elm = $("#list");
elm.html(elm.text());
```

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/yRwH7/

Comment: Thanks for the code. This renders the menu properly but the autocomplete "select" event does not trigger.